# Как вывести файл .glb на сайте?

Tags: javascript, 3d

Имеется файл с 3d моделью .glb, возможно ли как то вывести эту 3d на сайт без сторонних сервисов? Попадались ток сторонник сервисы формировки кода вставки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По сути `.glb` и есть `.gltf`, так что его получится отобразить модулем [GLTFLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader) у библиотеки [Three.js](https://threejs.org/), без проблем.

Проверить свою модель онлайн можно в редакторе Three.js - [ссылка](https://threejs.org/editor/).
Или в "средстве просмотра" GLTF форматов - [ссылка](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/)